# SQL query to return all records that has % in it

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table image with columns `id` (`number`), `url` (`varchar2(200)`).

Now I want to write a query to find all the urls which have character in it'%'. Does anyone how to write query for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One method uses `like`:

```
where url like '%$%%' escape '$'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use 'LIKE' to search for a character in the URL field.  The gotcha is that [the percent is used as a wildcard](http://%25%20matches%20any%20number%20of%20characters,%20even%20zero%20characters.) when doing a string comparison.  Do get around that functionality you need to [escape the percent sign](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-literals.html).

```
WHERE url LIKE '%\%%';
```

Comment: Thanks Kyle. I tried this "select * from  image where  url   like '%\%5C%' escape '\';" and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Already answered, I'll throw my two cents in for another alternative:

```
where instr(url, '%') > 0
```